# how to create a custom list c#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a custom list that will hold two values.

For example I have an enum:

```
public enum Type
{
   name,
   number,
   surname
}
```

so want I want to do is have a list that will hold the enum above, Type, and a value to go with it.

For example:

```
List<Type type, object value>
```

Please assist as to how i can go about accomplishing this.

Comment: Do you want to be able to look up 'value' based on 'type'? If not, you can just write a class that has a Type property and an Object property, and create a list of that class type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat.

A good option, if you only need to use this list inside a single method is to use a `List<Tuple<Type,object>>`. See [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) on MSDN.

If you do need to share the list across methods/classes, I suggest a custom type to hold both values:

```
public class MyValues
{
  public Type TheType { get; set; }
  public object TheObject { get; set; }
}
```

And use that with `List<MyValues>`.

Note: Your use of `object` as a generic type is a code smell. It defeats the reasons for using generics.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a generic list including a generic KeyValuePair or a Tuple:

```
List<KeyValuePair<Type, object>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<Type, object>>();

List<Tuple<Type, object>> myList = new List<Tuple<Type, object>>();
```

This might be a simple solution for your problem.

Comment: @Oded Yes. A dictionary is a unique collection. If he doesn't need unique values, he can use a Tuple<>. I updated my answer.

Comment: It would be ok to have only a Dictionary. Maybe you mean KeyValuePair<Type,object> ??

Comment: My point is that the OP needs _pairs_ of items in the list, not _collections_ of pairs of items.

Comment: And now your example will not compile ;)

Comment: @Oded Haha, now it should be ok :D

Answer (score 0):

If Type is going to be unique in the collection you can use a Dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<Type,object>
```

If Type is not going to be unique you can use a Tuple:

```
 List<Tuple<Type,object>>
```

Or you can make your own class and have a List of type your class as @oded suggested:

```
 List<MyValues>
```